# OS X - Signing installer/application

Tags: macos, certificate

I would like to sign my OS X installer using company certificate. I have .cer and .p12 files. I wonder if there is some way to do that without creating keychain. E.g. in 'productsign' tool flag --cert looks promising, but I can't find too much info about how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's signing tools *require* a keychain containing your organisation's signing identity.

The `cert` flag on [`productsign`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html) is used to embed an intermediate certificate. It is not used to specify the signing certificate.

It is possible to create a keychain containing your organisation's signing identity. This can then be used to sign your installer using the `keychain` flag. The separate keychain file can be managed with source code control or other file management tools; it remains separate from the user's login keychain.

Comment: I was expecting this, but still wanted to make sure. So if pkg creation is last step of my build procedure, every developer will have to deploy certificate on his machine, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want the developer to be able to sign, they must have the keychain on their Mac. You can sign the package as a separate pre-launch step. You could create an internal certificate for testing, see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17909